# Flutter: How do I implement Observer( ) mobX in TextFormField?

Tags: flutter, mobx, flutter-textformfield

So, I created this class where I have my @observables variables and my @action function. Everything is working right, all the returns and sets.

```
part 'location_controller.g.dart';

class LocationController = _LocationController with _$LocationController;

abstract class _LocationController with Store{
  double lat = 0.0;
  double long = 0.0;
  String erro = '';
  
  @observable
  String cep = '';

  @observable
  String city = '';

  @observable
  String uf = '';
  

  locationController() {
    getPosition();
  }

  @action
  getPosition() async {
    try {
      Position position = await _currentPosition();
      lat = position.latitude;
      long = position.longitude;

      Map<String, String> addressData =
          await LocationUtil.getAddressFromCoordinates(lat, long);
      cep = addressData['cep'];
      uf = addressData['uf'];
      city = addressData['city'];
    
    } catch (e) {
      erro = e.toString();
    }
  }
```

I also have this form page with TextFormField:

```
class RegisterForm extends StatefulWidget {
  const RegisterForm({super.key});

  @override
  State<RegisterForm> createState() => _RegisterFormState();
}

class _RegisterFormState extends State<RegisterForm> {
  final _formkey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final locationEC = LocationController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        color: Colors.white,
        margin: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
          child: Form(
            key: _formkey,
            child: Column(
              children: [                
                SizedBox(
                  height: 50,
                  width: double.infinity,
                  child: ElevatedButton.icon(
                    onPressed: () {
                      locationEC.getPosition();
                    },
                    icon: const Icon(Icons.location_on),
                    label: Text('Selecionar Localização',
                        style: TextStyles.instance.textRegular
                            .copyWith(fontSize: 16)),
                    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                        foregroundColor: ColorsApp.instance.primary,
                        elevation: 2,
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                          side: BorderSide(
                              color: ColorsApp.instance.primary, width: 1),
                        )),
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(height: 12),
                Observer(
                  builder: (_) => TextFormField(
                    enabled: false,
                    initialValue: locationEC.cep,
                    style: TextStyles.instance.textInput,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      labelText: 'CEP',
                      fillColor: ColorsApp.instance.background,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(height: 12),
                Row(
                  children: [
                    Flexible(
                      flex: 1,
                      child: Observer(
                        builder: (_) => TextFormField(
                          enabled: false,
                          initialValue: locationEC.uf,
                          style: TextStyles.instance.textInput,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            labelText: 'UF',
                            fillColor: ColorsApp.instance.background,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(
                      width: 5,
                    ),
                    Flexible(
                      flex: 4,
                      child: Observer(
                        builder: (_) => TextFormField(
                          enabled: false,
                          initialValue: locationEC.city,
                          style: TextStyles.instance.textInput,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            labelText: 'Cidade',
                            fillColor: ColorsApp.instance.background,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),                
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
  }
}
```

I implemented Observer() on each TextFormFiel in my form. My idea is that when the user clicks on the location button, getPosition() would take his coordinates and define his city, state and zip code from an API, placing them inside the variable in the LocationController.

After that, these values would appear inside the textformfield, like an initialValue. The problem is that it's not working, the form doesn't update with Observer(). What shoudl I do?

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation, when controller is not specified, it will assigned initialValue to the controller.text or empty string.

If you look at the implementation of TextFormField's initState method, you will see:

```dart
_createLocalController(widget.initialValue != null ? TextEditingValue(text: widget.initialValue!) : null);
```

The TextEditingValue is immutable. That's why you can never change its value.

To achieve the result, you may change to this:

```dart
Observer(
    builder: (_) => TextFormField(
        enabled: false,
        controller: TextEditingController(text: locationEC.cep), // use this instead
    ),
 ),
```